# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.SunFontManager with OpenJDK 11.0

Tags: java, openjdk-11, adoptopenjdk

We are facing this error since migration from OpenJDK 8 to OpenJDK 11.0.9 from [openjdk:11-jdk-slim](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk11-upstream-binaries/releases/tag/jdk-11.0.9.1%2B1).

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.SunFontManager
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:265)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:869)
```

```sh
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9.1+1, mixed mode)
```

Similar issue has been registered on RedHat here: http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1768935

However, as far as I understand, we are not using JDK from RedHat source code (even if openjdk-11 project is built and packaged by them, before being used by AdoptOpenJDK project....).

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, we moved to [Amazon Coretto 11](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/docker-install.html) which is currently based on following version.

```sh
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.9.12.1 (build 11.0.9.1+12-LTS, mixed mode)
```

No errors.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me with `openjdk:11-jdk-slim` docker image was to install `fontconfig`

and to add `--add-exports java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED` to the jvm parameters. E.g.:

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-server --add-exports java.desktop/sun.font=ALL-UNNAMED"

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS /app.jar" ]
```