# What is causing the 'Problem reading font data' exception in Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Google Cloud Dataflow - Problem reading font data

Hi,

I am trying to run a java application on Google cloud dataflow, however I am getting an exception

```
Error message from worker: java.lang.Exception:Problem reading font data.
```

The exception only appears when I use the `Dataflowrunner` , but when I use the `directRunner` it works fine on my machine

The issue is basically with `java.awt.Font` in the line

```
 Font.createFonts(stream)
                        .first()
                        .deriveFont(fontSize * FONT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER)
```

I am assuming that the docker image that dataflow runner uses, is missing on of the configurations, but I am not quiet sure what is it

Would appreciate if anyone has any idea about this and wants to help

Thanks!

Comment: where does Font data normally come from? A config file?

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks a lot for following up, I am fetching a custom font from GCS bucket, I checked that we get the bytestream, but the issue is with the java font library when `Font.createFonts(stream)`

I tried to get the `fontconfig` system property during my application lifetime, and it returned null, so I am suspecting that the default Apache Beam SDK that dataflow runner is using doesn't have `fontconfig` library

Comment: I also tried to use one of the default fonts ( I pulled the docker image apache/beam_java17_sdk:latest , as I am expecting it's the one used on dataflow runner ) 

I used the font ```Font("DejaVuSerif-Bold", Font.BOLD, 18)```

and now I ran into another Issue: 
```Error message from worker: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.font.SunFontManager\n        java.desktop/sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:266)\n        java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:863)\n```

Comment: I found a similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65683652/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-sun-font-sunfontmanag

it also mentioned the fontconfig

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y fonts-dejavu
apt-get install -y libfontconfig1-dev
```

Per this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html) also, register the created font with the graphics environment. For example:

```
try {
     GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
         GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
     ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("A.ttf"));
} catch (IOException|FontFormatException e) {
     //Handle exception
}
```

After registering the font with the graphics environment, the font is available in calls to getAvailableFontFamilyNames() and can be used in font constructors.

Comment: thanks for trying help, but I am using a different environment, where it requires to deal with external dependencies, I may not showed it in the main post, but I explained in the comments above